# What is this betting game where players place bets on any of 4 cards?

Tags: identify-this-game

all I remember is that there's 4 cards on the table and you can place bets on either of the 4 cards on the table and everyone places their chips on top of either of the 4 cards on the table. I forget the rest on how to play, does anybody at least have some recollection of the name or the rules on how to play? anything would be a big help.

Comment: Do you have more information?  What were the cards, Standard playing cards or something else?

If you are betting on a card what determines if a card has won? 

Do you recall if there was a theme at all?   The more information the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like **Newmarket**. There are A♠️, K♥️, Q♣️, J♦️ on the table known as the "horses" (the suits may vary, but there is one of each suit and they alternate colour). Players must place bets on the horses plus a separate pot.

A deck of cards is then dealt to all players plus one dummy hand - some players may receive one more card than the others. The player to the left of the dealer plays their lowest card (Aces are low) and whoever has the next sequentially higher card plays is until the sequence is eventually broken by either reaching a king, a card already played, or a card in the dummy hand. The last player to play a card then starts a new sequence with the lowest card they hold of the opposite colour. If they hold no such card, play passes to the next player clockwise.

If you play a horse card, you collect the bets placed on it, and the hand ceases when either one player plays their last card (in which case they take the chips in the pot) or, rarely, the hand is deadlocked by no-one having a card of the required colour. If bets on a horse or the pot are not claimed in one hand, they roll over to the next hand. To end the game, horses are retired from the game following a hand in which bets on them were claimed, which can lead to large sums going on the remaining ones.

Note: House rules seem to abound and what I've described is what I learnt as a child - I don't think there is a standard set of rules. I think there was the option for the dealer to pay chips into the pot for the right to look at the dummy hand and exchange his hand with it if he chose to.